# How to insert into combo box which is in Form A using Form B

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have two forms, Form A and Form B. On form A, i have a combo box which i read data from the database and it works fine but, now i want to add from Form B text box and it should automatically feed combo box from Form A. Please help if this is possible.

Form A Coding 
I have two forms, Form A and Form B. On form A, i have a combo box which i read data from the database and it works fine but, now i want to add from Form B text box and it should automatically feed combo box from Form A. It should also be able to edit and delete from Form B and automatically it will update/delete combo box items which will be on form A.

Saving code for Form B

```
    protected void btnAddDriver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region this
        List<tblAddDriver> _ListDivers = _dc.tblAddDrivers.Where(a => a.Fullname == txtDriversname.Text.ToString()).ToList();

        if (_ListDivers != null)
        {
            if (_ListDivers.Count() == 0)
            {
                tblAddDriver _Add = new tblAddDriver
                {
                    Fullname = txtDriversname.Text,
                    Surname = txtDriverssurname.Text,
                    Contact = txtcontact.Text,
                    RegNo = txtreg.Text

                };
                _dc.tblAddDrivers.InsertOnSubmit(_Add);
                _dc.SubmitChanges();
                lblresults.Visible = true;
                LoadData();
                lblresults.Text = "Thank You! , Your driver " + txtDriversname.Text + " " + txtDriverssurname.Text + " has been successfully added! ";
                ClearAll();

            }
        }
```

Form A - Reading from the db

```
    protected void Populate()
    {
        cboDriver.DataSource = _dc.tblDrivers.ToList();
        cboDriver.DataTextField = "DriversName";
        cboDriver.DataValueField = "DriversID";
        cboDriver.DataBind();
        cboDriver.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply add the new records to the database and refresh your datasource, which would then include the newly inserted values.

I also notice that you seem to have a mix of "Diver" and "Driver" in your code - is this intentional?

Comment: No problem. was the diver/driver thing intentional?

Comment: Good stuff. Glad I could help